# Remix + SSR + Redux (hydrate state)

Tags: redux, server-side-rendering, remix.run, hydration

I'm currently using Remix + Redux and need some direction on how to provide initial state to Redux so that it's coordinated with the state on the pre-rendered page.

> I am aware that Remix wants you to potentially forget traditional state management, but for many company settings that's a non-starter. My app also needs a lot of coordination.

I understand that you can fetch data from an endpoint *after* the app has already loaded, but I'm asking for SSR-time.